# DRF How can I get api key prefix used?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm trying to create an app that uses drf-api-key for authorization. And I want to monitor which api key used in every connection used to database, Is there a way to that?

I tried to get the value of headers.get("Authorization") I get a none value, I just want to retrieve the name of api key used or the prefix of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the token using:

```py
token = request.auth
```

Comment: I get a None value

Comment: Please provide more information about how your users can obtain the token and how you implemented this feature. If it's done correctly you should be able to get the token this way. Also, where do you want to get the key? Do you have access to the request object or not?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using

```
apiKey = request.headers['X-Api-Key'].split('.')[0]
```